# can't access the index page with Google AppEngine

Tags: google-app-engine

When trying to visit the homepage of my website `bob.com` (just an example), I expect `index.html` to get displayed. Instead, I got a 404.

To reach `index.html`, I got to manually browse `bob.com/index.html`.

What did I do wrong with my current `app.yaml` ?

```
runtime: php
env: flex

runtime_config:
  document_root: ./index.html


handlers:

# Handle the main page by serving the index page.
# Note the $ to specify the end of the path, since app.yaml does prefix matching.
- url: /*
  static_files: index.html
  upload: index.html
```

Answer (score 0):

This has done the trick:

```
runtime: php
env: flex

runtime_config:
  document_root: .
  front_controller_file: index.html
```